# How to adjust two arrays of points to a sine function?

Tags: java, curve-fitting, imagej

I'm working with ImageJ. I have two arrays of points (i.e `it[ ]`, `cmx[ ]`) and what I want is to adjust this to a *sine* function. I've been working with `CurveFitting` but I don't understand it very well. I also am having issues with `UserFunction`.

Is there an easier approach to this? If you have examples I would appreciate it.

Comment: You're going to need to be a little more specific. Asking bout how you have gotten stuck in one approach is specific and pragmatic but asking for easier methods is subjective and broad. Please see [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you mean by _sino_ function? Maybe *sine* function?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, sorry, it's sine function, ok, let me be more specific, i have an arrays of points, the lenght of the array is 32, what i want is to adjust this array to a sine function like "y = a + b*sin(c*x + d)", i already have the values of a, b, c and d. After i adjust it, i want the mos difference between the sine function and the array.

Comment: You're referring to the ImageJ [`CurveFitter`](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/ij/measure/CurveFitter.html) class, right?

Answer (score 0):

The following Groovy script is an example of running curve fitting on three data points:

```
import ij.measure.CurveFitter;

xData = [0,1,2];
yData = [3.1, 5.1, 6.9];

cv = new CurveFitter((double[]) xData.toArray(), (double[]) yData.toArray());

cv.doFit(CurveFitter.STRAIGHT_LINE);

println (cv.getResultString());
```

I'm not sure if `CurveFitter` allows fitting to trigonometric functions, there doesn't seem to be this option in the [available fitting types](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/ij/measure/CurveFitter.html). You might try a [high-degree polynomial fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting#Different_types_of_curve_fitting) instead.

You can also ask on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) or [mailing list](http://imagej.net/Mailing_Lists) regarding the implementation details of the `CurveFitter` class.